# How can I make a div into a slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering how I could make a div fit into a slider. What I mean by slider is a little box that when a button is pressed, a window emerges from the side, floating not pushing, and when the button it pressed again it retracts. How could I go about doing this?

My current code is listed here:

```
<div class="rec-anime-list-container">
<ul class="rec-anime-list container">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="column"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/120x80/000/fff" /></div></a>
            <div class="column rightcol"><p class="rec-anime-title">TITLE</p><strong class="sub">[Sub]</strong></div>
    </li> 
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="column"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/120xTITLE80/000/fff" /></div></a>
            <div class="column rightcol"><p class="rec-anime-title">TITLE</p><strong class="dub">[Dub]</strong></div>
    </li> 
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="column"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/120x80/000/fff" /></div></a>
            <div class="column rightcol"><p class="rec-anime-title">TITLE</p><strong class="sub">[Sub]</strong></div>
    </li> 
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="column"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/120x80/000/fff" /></div></a>
            <div class="column rightcol"><p class="rec-anime-title">TITLE</p><strong class="dub">[Dub]</strong></div>
    </li>     
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="column"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/120x80/000/fff" /></div></a>
            <div class="column rightcol"><p class="rec-anime-title">TITLE</p><strong class="sub">[Sub]</strong></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="column"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/120x80/000/fff" /></div></a>
            <div class="column rightcol"><p class="rec-anime-title">TITLE</p><strong class="dub">[Dub]</strong></div>
    </li>    
</ul>

<style>
.rec-anime-list-container {
    float:right;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.rec-anime-list {
    max-width: 480px;
}
.container li{
    float:left;
    width:230px;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.column {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle
}
.rec-anime-title {
    margin-top:0;
    color:gray;
    width:100px;
}
.sub {
    color:blue;
    font-size:16px;
}
.dub {
    color:red;
    font-size:16px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Well I have done similar before. I have social sliders on two websites, and a different kind of slider on another. You can see them here:

Comment: www.theaanetwork.net

Comment: I don't see any sliders, have you ever used jQuery or javascript to do this? Because you will need to.

Comment: Here, take a look at this: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Comment: If you hover over the icons on the left, or click the icon on the right (theaanetwork.net) things will slide out from the sides. That is what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery and changing the container div styles-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.rec-anime-list-container').click(function() {
    if (parseInt($(this).css('right')) < 0) {
      $(this).css('right', '5px');
    } else {
      $(this).css('right', '-350px');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.rec-anime-list-container {
    position: absolute;
    right: -350px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: right 300ms ease-in-out
}
.rec-anime-list {
    max-width: 480px;
}
.container li{
    float:left;
    width:230px;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.column {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle
}
.rec-anime-title {
    margin-top:0;
    color:gray;
    width:100px;
}
.sub {
    color:blue;
    font-size:16px;
}
.dub {
    color:red;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rec-anime-list-container">
<ul class="rec-anime-list container">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="column"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/120x80/000/fff" /></div></a>
            <div class="column rightcol"><p class="rec-anime-title">TITLE</p><strong class="sub">[Sub]</strong></div>
    </li> 
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="column"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/120xTITLE80/000/fff" /></div></a>
            <div class="column rightcol"><p class="rec-anime-title">TITLE</p><strong class="dub">[Dub]</strong></div>
    </li> 
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="column"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/120x80/000/fff" /></div></a>
            <div class="column rightcol"><p class="rec-anime-title">TITLE</p><strong class="sub">[Sub]</strong></div>
    </li> 
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="column"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/120x80/000/fff" /></div></a>
            <div class="column rightcol"><p class="rec-anime-title">TITLE</p><strong class="dub">[Dub]</strong></div>
    </li>     
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="column"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/120x80/000/fff" /></div></a>
            <div class="column rightcol"><p class="rec-anime-title">TITLE</p><strong class="sub">[Sub]</strong></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="column"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/120x80/000/fff" /></div></a>
            <div class="column rightcol"><p class="rec-anime-title">TITLE</p><strong class="dub">[Dub]</strong></div>
    </li>    
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah this is essentially what I want to do. Thanks for the help! Question though, if I wanted the div to be hidden until a button is clicked (a button attached to the top right for instance), how could I implement it?

Answer (score -1):

Using Jquery

```
total_imgs = 7     //total li elements
j=0;              
function imgSlider()
    {
      t = setTimeout(function () {
      $(".rec-anime-list li").removeClass("display");
      $("#list"+(j%total_imgs)).addClass("display");
      j++;
      imgSlider(j,0);
      },1000);
    }
imgSlider();  // initiate the slider
```

add this to your css

```
 .display{display:block !important}
```

you can find the working model at https://jsfiddle.net/skk46gu6/

Comment: Read the question and it's comments again.